# Repaint doesn't work when changing variable

Tags: java, repaint

I am very new to developing with java but I have some general coding experience. I know wanted to draw a "picture/fractal" with a function I created. I got all the code done and I wanted to automatically move the "fractal" by just adding to the function XOFF, (I have a timer) now I wanted the variable to automatically increase so that it scrolls through the picture. I tried using repaint and revalidate but it doesnt work :(

and i know that i wrote MandelBrotSet even though it doesn't have anything to do with it ^^

```java
package Pack1;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JComponent implements ActionListener {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public static final int WIDTH = 1000;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 800;
    public int XOFF = 0;
    public int YOFF = 0;

    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private Timer timer;

    public Main(){

        buffer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        timer = new Timer(10, this);
        renderMandelBrotSet();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mandelbrot Set");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override 
    public void addNotify() {       
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        timer.start();
    }

    public void renderMandelBrotSet() {
        System.out.println(XOFF);
        int vx = 0;
        int vy = 0;
        int zoom = 1;

        for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                vx = ((x - WIDTH/2));
                vy = ((y - HEIGHT/2));
                vx = vx + XOFF;
                vy = vy + 0;
                int color = (int) (Math.abs(vx)/Math.sqrt(Math.abs(vy))*(vx/zoom));    //calculatePoint((x - WIDTH/2), (y - HEIGHT/2) );

                buffer.setRGB(x, y, color);
            }
    }


    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        XOFF++;
        renderMandelBrotSet();
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }
}
```

I hope the code makes sense..., I am sorry if I forgot to mention anything. Feel free to ask me if you need something.

Comment: Cutting out unnecessary code is good, but I think you've cut to much.  Take what you have above and get it working with the minimum number of additions.  I don't think we're going to be able to guess at the problem, it will require code we can run and test.  See: [mcve]

Comment: Thanks :) Im adding the whole code!

Comment: I agree with @markspace -- I don't see how we can tell without guessing what is wrong based on non-compilable non-runnable snippets of code. We don't want the whole program (probably) but enough to make it runnable and show us the problem. A suggestion though: don't override `paint(Graphics g)` but rather override `protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)` in a drawing class that extends JPanel. Don't forget to call the super's painting method on the first line of your override, if only to allow the dirty pixels to be removed.

Comment: For my example of Mandelbrot set coding, please check out the code in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41213151/522444).

Comment: And before you add "the whole code" please read or re-read the [mre] link. You also don't want to overwhelm us with code that is not necessary.

Comment: Also, threading can become an issue here since deep Mandelbrot calculations can take a bit of time to complete, and so a decent solution will likely need to use a background thread.

Comment: The whole isn't much longer than the version i showed before and i don't thing that i cant removing anything without making it un-runnable. But thank you anyway! I will read through the post!

Comment: The (new) code you posted works for me (I see an image).  What were you expecting to see?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels thanks i tried it out and know it works!! But i can only see the changes when i resize the window...Is there a solution where it just does the job automatically??

Comment: @markspace i wanted to see the image automatically scroll to the right by just adding the XOFF variable to the function...it is now working but only if i resize the window i see the changes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `addNotify` is your problem.  That method already does something, and the way you overrode it you don't seem to perform any of the actions that its documentation says it should.  Just get rid of it, and move its code elsewhere.

This seems to work for me.  I also slowed your timer down to 100 ms since I know from experience that Java Swing isn't really capable of updating as quickly as that. 100 ms to 250 ms is a good range for updating Swing.

I also got rid of `revalidate` because that's only for when a component is added or removed, or changes size.  You only need to repaint since your image doesn't change size.

(Hovercraft pointed out that the code really should override `paintComponent`, not `paint`.  He is quite correct; this is explained in the tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html )

(And while I'm fixing stuff up I might as well point out that [Swing is not thread safe,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) and the GUI creation (including the image and the timer) really needs to be done on the GUI thread.)

```
package quicktest;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

/**
 *
 * @author Brenden
 */
public class MandelbrotSet {

}


class Main extends JComponent implements ActionListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public static final int WIDTH = 800;
    public static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    public int XOFF = 0;
    public int YOFF = 0;

    private BufferedImage buffer;
    private Timer timer;


    public Main(){
       SwingUtilities.invokeLater( this::createGui );
    }

    private void createGui() {
        buffer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        timer = new Timer(100, this);
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension( WIDTH, HEIGHT ) );
        renderMandelBrotSet();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mandelbrot Set");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(this);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        timer.start();
    }       

//    @Override 
//    public void addNotify() {
//        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
//        timer.start();
//    }

    public void renderMandelBrotSet() {
        System.out.println(XOFF);
        int vx = 0;
        int vy = 0;
        int zoom = 1;

        for(int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            for(int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
                vx = ((x - WIDTH/2));
                vy = ((y - HEIGHT/2));
                vx = vx + XOFF;
                vy = vy + 0;
                int color = (int) (Math.abs(vx)/Math.sqrt(Math.abs(vy))*(vx/zoom));    //calculatePoint((x - WIDTH/2), (y - HEIGHT/2) );

                buffer.setRGB(x, y, color);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent( g );
       System.err.println( "Repainting..." );
       g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       System.err.println( "Timer: XOFF=" + XOFF );
        XOFF++;
        renderMandelBrotSet();
//        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

}
```

Comment: One plus, but ***please*** do me a favor and 1) override `paintComponent` and 2) call the super's method. No sense propagating bad code.